# Find the exponent of the binomial below

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Developing the binomial $[(x+\frac{1}{x})(x-\frac{1}{x})]^n$ we obtain independent term equal to $70$. The value $n$ is equal to?($S:n=8$)

$(x+\frac{1}{x})((x-\frac{1}{x})]^n=(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2} )^n\\
T_{p+1} = C(n,p) .x^{2{^({n-p)}}}.(\frac{-1}{x^2})^p =C(n,p) .x^{2n-2p-2p}.(-1)^p \implies 2n - 4p = 0$

$ \therefore n = 2p$

$T_{(\dfrac{n}{2}+1)} = C(2p,p).(x)^0 .(-1)^p \implies \dfrac{2p!}{p!.p!}.(-1)^p = 70$

How to finish?

Comment: What’s T, what’s S, what’s an independent term. Please clarify things. Are you just noticing that 8 choose 4 is 70?

Comment: @Eric ...T = General Term of Binomial Expansion is a Basic Expression . $S$ = Solution to the question

Comment: Err, you should put that in your question and avoid putting variables without defining them first. What’s obvious to you is confusing to others, especially if it’s nonstandard notation. Is independent term supposed to mean constant term or term independent of x? That’s nonstandard. It’s really not clear what you’re asking for - do you know that $n=8$, or are you trying to prove that? If you’re trying to show it, note that the binomial strictly increases with $n$, and it works at 8, so tada.

Comment: @Eric  In the expansion of $(a + b)^n$, the term which is free from the variables is known as the independent term.

Comment: I tried to make it as simple and clear as possible. Your pattern may not be the same in my country.
Term independent is standard in all countries as I posted the definition.
For me the question is very clear and very simple. Find the exponent $(n)$ of the binomial expansion given that the independent term is 70.
The answer of the question is $n = 8$.
In short, after my attempt I need to calculate $C(2p, p) , (-1)p= 70$.
I am sorry if the question was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have ${2p \choose p}= \pm 70$. Central binomial coefficients as a function of $p$ are strictly increasing, and testing numbers gives 20 for $p=3$, $70$ for $p=4$ and $252$ for $p=5$. For $p<4$ it is too small in magnitude and $p>4$ are too big, while 4 itself works, so $p=4$, $n=2\cdot 4=8$ is the answer.